# Jupyter Ipywidgets behave Inconsistently when displaying and refreshing

Tags: python-2.7, pandas, jupyter-notebook, bokeh, ipywidgets

I've made a jupyter notebook that displays some graphs and dataframes. I can then change the widget values to refresh the dataframes and graphs.

I'm running into two problems:

1. Every time I run the book for the first time after opening Jupyter notebook, I get this:

[image]

Yet when I run all cells again, I get the desired output:

[image]

2. Every time I use the widgets and make a change, the notebook eventually refreshes correctly, but for some reason it continually outputs the top few graphs, seems to clear the output, then show them again, then clear output, and after a few iterations of this, is able to display everything. Here is my event handler:

   ```
   def handle_submit(sender):
       clear_output(wait=True)

       start = w.slider_start.value.strftime('%Y-%m-%d')
       end = w.slider_end.value.strftime('%Y-%m-%d')

       zval = z.value
       yval = y.value
       xval = x.value

       df_dlm,df_dgo,df_stats = show_stats(zval,yval,xval,start,end)
       df_e = show_stats_exp(zval,yval,xval,start,end)

       display_dataframe(df_stats)
       plot_lines_e(df_e)
       dfx = prepare_data(df_dlm,df_dgo)
       plot_lines(dfx)
       plot_scatter(dfx)
   ```

where the `display_dataframe`, `plot_lines`, and `plot_scatter` functions all have a "display" type line in them to actually show the graph since `%matplotlib inline` does not play well with ipywidgets...feels like that has something to do with it, but not sure how to get around this.

FYI the graphs are done in Bokeh, certain dataframes are plotted at matplotlib objects.

Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 0):

That warning is just a bug that should be fixed in the next version of ipywidgets I believe. In the mean time the only thing that you can do is wait ~10-20 seconds after loading or reloading the notebook and the "trusted" box appears in the right hand corner as picture below;
[image]

Try executing all of your code only after you see that box come up.